# Removing my averages

Tags: average

thanks for your time and apologies if this is far too simple for this group.

I am trying to remove my average from a total average.  Meaning:

The total average for a subset of data is 55.  I am 29% of this subset and my average is 52.

If I were to remove myself from the equation, how could I find the average of the remaining 71% without me?

Answer (score 7):

Let $x$ represent the average of the $71\%$ subset.  Then the following equation holds:

$$(0.29) \cdot 52 + (0.71) \cdot x = 55$$

Does that make sense, and can you take it from here?

Comment: This is very nice!

Comment: YES!! Thanks so much! I can take it from there!

Answer (score 4):

Let $x$ denote your average and let $y$ denote the average of the rest. The overall average is $0.29x+0.71y=55$. You know that $x=52$. Just solve for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Your contribution to the total sum is $0.29\times52$, so what you need is $(55-0.29\times52)/(1-0.29)\approx 56.23$

Answer (score 0):

Let's take there are 100 people in all.So total 100% = 100 people.

Therefore total of 100 people with average 55 is 5500

Out of that 29% = 29 has average of 52.So total would be 29*52 = 1508

Therefor remaining 71% would be 5500-1508 = 3992

Therefore average of this 71% would be 3992/71 = 56.22.

Therefore answer is 56.